# Browser testing for JavaScript plugin, in independant versions of each browser

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, modernizr

I am building 3d gallery plugin, a pretty simplistic one, something that uses CSS-3 properties. Now as it is, not all browsers support 3d transforms, so obviously I have  to write code to accommodate browsers that don't have access to css-3 at all.

As a matter of fact, I need to write almost, I need to write a whole set of different functionality for older browsers. Well, there are a few solutions to this I see:

- Write code to check if browser supports (I had a question posted a few day ago, on [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484025/feature-detection-for-css3-transition-property)).
- Use a library like Modernizer, and make your life easy.

Well say I do any of the above, and now I have code like below:

```
if(supports3d) {
    // use css-3 properties and make the gallery look awesome
}  else {
    // Fall back gracefully , no cool transforms , transitions , preserve-3d etc. just make it look basic. 
}
```

Now here's where the problem begins, on my PC , Win-7 and latest Chrome, I will always see the code executed in the if condition. I have no way to test how my code will look in earlier versions of Chrome or IE or FF, say for each browser, I would like to test my code for each version, just like I can test my code in the latest chrome browser.

A tool like [Browser Stack](https://www.browserstack.com), might help me see how my plugin gets displayed in all browsers, but what I wanted to know is, is it possible to run all versions of browsers on my PC and be able to run test in each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install multiple versions of Firefox using the procedure here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/939994#answer-376060. It's a little bit involved, but not too bad. You have to do a custom install to a different location for each version, then setup each version to use a separate profile.

IE 11 has a handy "document mode" feature where you can set it to behave like older versions of IE. To use it, press F12 to open the developer tools, then change then use the dropdown where it says "Edge" to pick your version. IE 6 is mysteriously left out though, so if you need to test on IE 6, you'll need another solution like a virtual machine.

Chrome, sadly, is not so easy. You can get older versions of it from http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/. There are various procedures for running multiple Chrome versions in the question: [Can I run multiple versions of Google Chrome on the same machine? (Mac or Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window). The simplest by far is just to install the different versions in separate user accounts. But, if this seems too cumbersome, you can check out some of the other solutions in that thread.